# How to find source object of added button

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamically-generated

I have dynamically added button to a listbox.
I'm working with that button and I have to know where this button is located.

I have this method:

```
private void addNewButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(sender.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(Control)))
        {
            Control formControl = (Control)sender;
            switch (formControl.Name)
            {
                case "addSound20":
                case "addSound21":
                case "addSound23":
                case "addSound24":
                case "addSound25":
                case "addSound26":
                    MessageBox.Show("test: " + formControl.Name);
                    // there I need to know, where is this button located
                    break;
                default:
                    MessageBox.Show("exception: default");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I find the source object of my button?

EDIT: I have some ListBoxes in mainWindow - and I need to know, which ListBox contains that Button I'm working with. Every object has specific name - for example "button20", "listBox22", etc.

Comment: When you say source object of button - What do you mean? The button it self when clicked or it's immediate parent?

Comment: Look at my edit.
I mean this - every button is located in dynamically added ListBoxes. ListBoxes with some name, and some properties.

Comment: Note: `if(sender.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(Control)))
` could be written as `if (sender is Control)`.

Comment: `formControl.Parent` should do it, (not got time to test)

Comment: Parent works. Do u know, how can I acess items in formControl.Parent?

Comment: like what? you can cast it if you know what type it will be

Comment: @Sayse I want to remove button from that listbox. I'm trying to use 'formControl.Parent.GetType().Items.Remove(formControl);' but this code cant be compiled.

Comment: `GetType()` is not casting - `((ListBox)control.Parent).Items...` I'll add as answer if you want.

Comment: @Sayse Yes please, post it as answer. This is exactly what i want. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from your last comment, you can cast and use `Parent`

```
((ListBox)formControl.Parent).Items.Remove(formControl);
```

Note: Parent can return null you may wish to check it

`formControl.Parent != null && formControl.Parent is ListBox`

Answer (score 0):

You can use VisualTreeHelper to find the parent of any control... below method can help you..

```
        public static T FindAncestor(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
            where T : DependencyObject
        {
            var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dependencyObject);

            if (parent == null) return null;

            var parentT = parent as T;
            return parentT ?? FindAncestor(parent);
        }
```

You can call this method like `LisBox lisbox = FindAncestor(formControl);`